# External Monitor Resolution doesn't go above 1024x768

Tags: 10.10, xorg, display

I am trying to use a 24" external monitor as the primary monitor for my Asus EEE netbook. When I connect it, it works properly, except the max resolution available is 1024x768. Usually, I'd go into the xorg.conf and add it, but 10.10 doesn't seem to have an xorg.conf. I read on another question here that I could simply go into recovery mode and make one using `X -configure` and moving the new xorg.conf into /X11/ but that caused X to not even start. I renamed xorg.conf to a temp name for now.

What should I be trying? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, we might have similar problems, so let's be sure first. Is your monitor recognized by the system, or do you get "Unknown Monitor"? and, does "dmesg" gives you "raw EDID"? (I have a desktop PC BTW).

Comment: Unknown Monitor. Didn't try dmesg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type:

```
cvt 1280 1024 60
```

Will see something like:

```
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00" 109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

Copy this line except for the Modeline part

Pass this copied text to `xrandr --newmode` like this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00" 109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

Add the new mode to the proper device (in my case, VGA1. Find this via xrandr)

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1280x1024_60.00"
```

You will now see the new resolution on the resolution options.

I wrote a more detailed tutorial here: http://shanereustle.com/blog/force-screen-resolutions-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I use Jupiter with my eee pc.
Everything works like a charm. It can be used to switch desktop resolution

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter jupiter-support-eee
```

Then just click on its icon, choose resolution and monitor configuration.