# Monitor resolution messed up, monitor is unknown

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, display, resolution

Is there anyway to reset my monitor? My moitor is using the xorg.conf file. I use 10.04, without any Graphics Card. My monitor is an Acer X193W, with a native resolution of 1440x900.

This is my xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Configured Screen Device"
    Device  "Configured Video Device"
    Monitor "Test"
    DefaultDepth 16
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 16
        Modes   "1440x900_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

#Section "Device"
#   Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
#   HorizSync 
#   VertRefresh
#EndSection
```

I still cant view the native resolution, even when defined in the xorg file. An way I can revert to the default, or delete some files, to make the system detect the monitor again?

[My last resort is the cvt method, and adding it to the xrandr file.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13783/external-monitor-resolution-doesnt-go-above-1024x768)

EDIT: I use Intel Drivers. My `/proc/fb` contains 
`0 VGA16 VGA`

[image]

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Dumped output to http://pastebin.com/zk8wqb8e

Comment: Had the same problem with an nVidia card and an Acer monitor. Couldn't understand it as it seemed to happen randomly, and in Windows 7 as well as in Ubuntu. Turns out that this happens whenever I boot the computer before I turn on the monitor(!). So at least in my setup, turning on the monitor before I turn on the computer fixed it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to replace `moitor` with `monitor`, `cant` with `can't`, and `An way` with `Any way`.

Answer (score 2):

The monitor reports its dimensions using [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data). Most probably the monitor does not report correctly the EDID information. In addition, newer X.Org is strict about EDID information.

So, how to figure out if this is an EDID issue;

1. Install the `read-edid` package with `sudo apt-get install read-edid`
2. Get the EDID information with `sudo get-edid | parse-edid`
3. Finally, post the information here (use `pastebin`).

Answer (score 1):

this is a old question, but maybe I can help someone else with this problem:

I had the same problem, I have the same monitor (acer x193w) and I was not able to set the resolution correct (1440x900). the solution was very simple although I was looking for it for two days. This is the solution: go into the menu of the monitor, select reset and reset your monitor configurations. After this detect your displays again (in the monitor settings or in the nvidea settings) and now my monitor was recognized and I was able to select the correct resolution.

I fount this solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=836695).

Answer (score 0):

**The following are my results.**

Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

```
VBE version 300
VBE string at 0x2110 "Brookdale-G Graphics Chip Accelerated VGA BIOS"
```

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

```
Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
Function supported
Call successful

Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 transfers
Monitor and video card combination supports DDC2 transfers
0 seconds per 128 byte EDID block transfer
Screen is not blanked during DDC transfer
```

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

```
Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
Function supported
Call successful
```

parse-edid: EDID checksum passed.

```
# EDID version 1 revision 2
```

Section "Monitor"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:0
    # Block type: 2:0 3:0
    # Block type: 2:0 3:0
    # Block type: 2:0 3:0
    Identifier "OEC:0177"
    VendorName "OEC"
    ModelName "OEC:0177"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:0
    # Block type: 2:0 3:0
    # Block type: 2:0 3:0
    # Block type: 2:0 3:0
    # DPMS capabilities: Active off:yes  Suspend:yes  Standby:yes

```
# Block type: 2:0 3:0
# Block type: 2:0 3:0
# Block type: 2:0 3:0
# Block type: 2:0 3:0
```

EndSection