# When using monitor in TwinView, the OS doesn't recognize its native resolution, why?

Tags: vga

"Monitor A": Samsung 940N 19" LCD [VGA connection]
"Monitor B": Samsung 940N 19" LCD [VGA connection]
VGA card: Nvidia Geforce GT220 [has 1 VGA, 1 HDMI, 1 DVI]
So I'm using a "DVI to VGA" converter.

Under Windows7: The OS recognizes the 1280x1024 native resolution in both monitors, hurray!

Under Ubuntu 11.04: The OS recognizes one of the monitors ("Monitor A") as a Samsung, OK! (resolution is good too!). BUT: the other monitor ("Monitor B") is recognized as "Unknown", and uses 1024*768. (the "other" monitor is the one that's with a DVI to VGA converter - "Monitor B"). I installed the NVIDIA driver too, but it still recognizes the second monitor - "Monitor B" (with the DVI to VGA converter) as it would has a maximum resolution of 1024*768.

Question: How could I "tell" Ubuntu to use the "other" monitor - "Monitor B" with 1280*1024 (the native resolution)???

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/13783/external-monitor-resolution-doesnt-go-above-1024x768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the DVI converter solved the problem.

Comment: how did you manage that then? Ps could you mark your post as solved please :)

Comment: we though it will be an OS issue because it worked under Windows, and didn't worked under Ubuntu.... but we bought another DVI to VGA converter and the problem is solved... :D

Comment: i still can accept my own anser, it says it need 3 more hours to allow accepting :\